# How To Style Mat-Ink-Bar with Different Color for Each Mat-Tab In Angular Material?

Tags: javascript, css, angular, tabs, angular-material

I am trying to style each `mat-tab` with a different color at all time, whether the tab is active or not. I am able to style the `mat-ink-bar` for all tabs but I am having a hard time figuring this out for each tab. Please help.

```css
/* label style */
.mat-tab-label{
  background: green;
  color:white;
}

/* ink bar style */
.mat-tab-group.mat-primary .mat-ink-bar{
  background: yellow;
  height: 10px;
} 

/* Trying to style the second mat-ink bar */
.mat-tab-group.mat-primary > .USD  .mat-ink-bar{
  background: blue;
  height: 10px;
}
```

```html
<mat-tab-group>
  <mat-tab class="USD" label="USD">USD</mat-tab>
  <mat-tab class="AUD" label="AUD">AUD</mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="AED">AED</mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="CAD">CAD</mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be a stupid answer, but have you tried just doing this?

```
  .USD{
  background: blue;
  height: 10px;
}
```

Comment: @AllJs I was thinking about this question and I have some ideas.  Any chance you could post more of your html code to show the `mat-tab` and `mat-ink-bar` ? Also, does this work? `mat-tab-group > .USD {
  background: blue;
  height: 10px;
} `